# Can multiple (or the same) methods be running simultaneously on one instance?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm attempting to make a video game and am worried about working with my world object in multiple threads.

If I have a method "doAction(Action action)" and two threads are calling this method simultaneously on the same object, could they mess with each other? Is there anything I have to do like make a queue?

The method will update various entities of the game (depending on the action). Each entity's "fields" are already a ConcurrentHashMap, but I'm not sure if this is necessary.

Because of user interaction, besides the basic time step method which would place calls to doAction, there could also be other calls from entities in between time steps or maybe at the exact same time.

I don't want to leave it be and run into hard to debug problems later on. Note that my understanding of threads is limited, so correct me if I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: That depends: Does your class have any fields that are updated by the method?

Comment: I'll edit the question

Comment: It's complicated, although each entity is a ConcurrentHashMap, operation on each entity is thread-safe, but if one action updates multiple entities, it may be dangerous, there are also other dangerous cases. I think you should first learn the definition of thread-safe before you starting design your game.

Comment: You question is too broad as written, however it sounds like you should `synchronize` your `doAction()` method.

Comment: this is a good question. It is broad because many novice programmers face it, and not "too broad" to be closed. Please reopen it.

Comment: "could they mess with each other?" - yes. "Is there anything I have to do like make a queue?" - yes, make the methods "synchronized" and Java would make all necessary queues under the hood.